# Creating symbolic link to all files/folders in a path

Tags: batch-file

I have d:\folder1 and e:\folder2
What I want to do is create a simlink for each file/folder/ from d:\folder1 in e:\folder2. Recursive if possible

What I tried so far is

```
for %f in (d:\folder1\*) do mklink /d %~dp0\%f
```

It only created some links for files which seem to not work

Does anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you're only using one % for your variables, I'd assume you're doing this from cmd prompt. `%~dp0` won't resolve from the cmd prompt. You have to put that in a batch file and double the %'s. Since you're using the `/d` switch for `mklink` That implies that you want to create a directory symbolic link. If that's the case, use:

```
For /d %%f in (d:\folder1\*) do mklink /d "%%~df\%%~nflink" "%~dp0%%~nf"
```

Notice there is no backslash. %%~dp0 already includes it.

If you need to create simlinks to files as well, use

```
For /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d "d:\folder1"') do mklink "%%~dpnflink" "%~dp0%%~nxf"
```

Comment: How do I set destination address?

Comment: @JaberAlNahian: For /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d "d:\source-folder\*.ext"') do mklink ".\target-folder\target-subfolder\%%~nxf" "%~dp0%%~nxf" The "f" is the input %%f before the in. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for